# Line integral using variable change

Tags: integration, determinant

The variable change theorem is the following:

$$\int_B f = \int_A f \circ g \cdot |det\mathcal Jg|$$

So to calculate the following line integral:

$$\int_C(xy)ds$$ where $C = g(t) = (cost, sint),0<t<1$

Shouldn't this be correct?
$$\int_0^1 cost\cdot sint \cdot |det \mathcal Jg|$$

But how do I calculate $|det \mathcal Jg|$?

Comment: This is the absolute value of the Jacobian of your change of variable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: @julien how do I build the Jacobian of g?

Comment: Your change of variable must be a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself for the formula to hold. Here $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, so you can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No change of variable here, just a standard line integral computation, with parametrization $r(t)=(\cos t, \sin t)$ with velocity $\|r'(t)\|=\sqrt{(-\sin t)^2+(\cos t)^2}$:
$$
\int_C xy \;ds=\int_0^1 \cos t\sin t\sqrt{(-\sin t)^2+(\cos t)^2} dt.
$$

Since $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$,  we are left with
$$
\int_0^1\cos t\sin tdt=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sin (2t) dt=\frac{-\cos (2)+1}{4}.
$$